# Deployed Mac app does not open on Macs older than late 2014

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I've deployed a Mac app that runs fine on Macs made in late 2014 or later (the operating system seems to not matter as an old Mac running High Sierra will still not run the app), but with older Macs it always crashes with this error:

ImagineyeFree quit unexpectedly

[image]

Notes:                 Translocated Process

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

how do I solve this problem? The app is written in QT and uses 64bit libraries....are all Mac's older than late 2014 all 32bit? So a 64bit app will not run on them?

I have this line in my QT .pro file

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4)

...does this make a difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you compiled your code with a later XCode than what these computers have, and you didn't target the old versions of macOS/OS X.

Do remember that older Mac cannot upgrade to the latest macOS, and even some people prefer to keep old versions. In that case, if you don't explicitly set the deployment target to say 10.11, everything below the default value (which is the current macOS you have) won't be able to execute your code.

Newer compilers would also use instructions that are not compatible with old CPUs, so also verify that you are not using any "new" instruction set like AVX.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly.... so to solve this problem, I need find an older Mac and then re-build the app on there?

Comment: That's one option, but then the issue is that older XCode don't have access to newer C++ features. The proper way to do it is to change the deployment target OS in the XCode properties and set it to the earliest macOS you want to support.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591988/best-practice-for-osx-10-x-backwards-compatability

Comment: Also added a mention about instruction set which could trigger these errors as well.